# 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'MenuItem

Tags: reactjs

I tried doing npm start, and receiving the following error.

```
./src/App.js
104:16-24 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'MenuItem
```

How can I fix this? I tried doing `npm install`

**Reference Code:**

```
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, NavItem, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In new versions of bootstrap it is `Dropdown.Item` not `MenuItem`. [Check here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns)

Comment: hi, where did you get the list of deprecated replacements? it worked ! I now get this error, 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Panel'.  ?  I need a list of word replace

Comment: I also got another error for Label

Comment: another question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599862/react-bootstrap-does-not-contain-an-export-named-label