# 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Label'

Tags: reactjs

I tried doing npm start, and receiving the following error.

```
./src/App.js
104:16-24 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Label'.
```

How can I fix this? I tried doing `npm install`. Is there a replacement component? I just changed MenuItem to Dropdown.

**Reference Code:**

```
import { PageHeader, Label, Grid, Row, Col, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: Seems like your referencing code is expecting an older version of `react-bootstrap`? Which version is listed in your `package.json` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is `FormLabel` Now.  [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/overview/)